# How should I create a new php.ini for MAC OSx?

Tags: php, apc

I'm new to PHP development so I'm not sure how I should go about creating a PHP.ini file from scratch. It seems that although PHP 5 is preinstalled on this operating system the php.ini does not exist by default. I am installing the APC extensions and I need to load them via the php.ini configuration file.

Is there a template or something that I should use? Or can I just create a new php.ini and add the section that I am interested in?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The php.ini does exist as it's a defalt php config file, however it needs to be renamed to be useable, it should appear as php.ini.default and you need to be logged in as root user to rename it or just open the file, copy the contents within and paste it in a new file, name it php.ini and save in the same directory.

Comment: Or, use `sudo cp php.ini.default php.ini`